# composite component ending up in wrong directory with jboss jsf tools and m2eclipse?

Tags: jsf-2, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp, jboss-tools

When using JBOSS Tools, M2E and M2E-WTP creating a new composite component wants to put the newly created component in the wrong directory. It also looks for components in the wrong directory.

It should be putting it in the directory:

```
src/main/webapp/resources/components/group-name/tagname.xhtml
```

but instead it is looking for it (and a quick fix creates file) in:

```
target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/resources/components/group-name/tagname.xhtml
```

Here are the versions I am using:

JBoss Tools RichFaces for Eclipse Version:
3.2.1.v20110730-1214-H169-Final

M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse
Version: 1.0.0.20110607-2117

Maven Integration for WTP
Version: 0.13.1.20110728-1800

### Update:

Seems to pick the first path in .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component file. Changing the non m2e to be first seems to make it want to put it in the right place.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="hcbb">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="hcbb"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/hcbb/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

However, it is still complaining about missing or invalid attributes and not doing auto completion on the custom components.. Not sure if JSF Tools even does that though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is fixed in later release of joss tools 3.3.x.

If not please open bug and we'll look at it.